Помогите разобраться с числом и запятыми
В каком числе должно стоять сказуемое?
Надо ли обособить "вместе со студентом-практикантом"?
Именно он вместе со студентом-практикантом выступил(и?) организатором(и?) проекта.

• Я бы написала так (сказуемое в единственном числе; без запятых):
Именно он вместе со студентом-практикантом выступил организатором проекта.
• §186. Сказуемое при подлежащем типа брат с сестрой:

2. При наличии в конструкции слов вместе, совместно употребляется форма единственного числа сказуемого, например: Операцию делал профессор вместе с ассистентом; Режиссер совместно со своими помощниками подготовил новые мизансцены в спектакле. Ср.: Еще мальчиком Русаков вместе со своим отцом уехал от безземелья с переселенцами в Сибирь (Т. Семушкин).

• Примеры
Именно он вместе с Богданом Бельским присутствовал при смерти Грозного и сам потом с крыльца объявил о случившемся народу (А. Попов. Все тайны Москвы).
Именно он вместе с чеченскими особистами должен был сопровождать чемоданчик в Москву (В. Власов. Мономах. Снова в деле).
• Дополнительно о запятых
Стоит отметить, что обособление оборота "вместе со студентом-практикантом" возможно.

Во многих случаях... обособление или необособление обстоятельства зависит от степени распространенности оборота, его близости к основной части предложения, наличия добавочных оттенков значения, места по отношению к сказуемому, стилистической задачи и т. д., поэтому обособление факультативно. [Розенталь]

В свое время именно он, вместе с Петром Лукичом Проскуриным, образовывал фонд для этой премии (С. Н. Есин. Дневник).

Обособление возможно, надо смотреть по контексту: Именно Он, // вместе со студентом-практикантом,// выступил организатором проекта.
Здесь оборот имеет скорее уточняющее значение. Студент-практикант вряд ли был равноценным участником проекта, а иначе бы было бы указано его имя. Оборот по значимости уходит на второй план речи. Это проверка смысла.
Кроме того, при равноценном участии и отсутствии обособления более ожидаемым был бы вариант согласования во мн. числе:Именно они вместе со студентом-практикантом / выступили организаторами проекта.
Ответ на mail ru: Нужно видеть полностью предложение.
Проверка структуры предложения. Обособлению оборота способствует наличие слова ИМЕННО, тогда основное сообщение выглядит так: Именно он выступил организатором проекта. Ударение при обособлении уточняющего оборота падает на "именно он", а дальше следует пауза. (Это видно и по приведенному примеру из первого ответа.)
Примечание. Вообще говоря при решении задач на факультативное обособление обстоятельственных оборотов интонационный анализ особенно важен. В этм случае (при отсутствии обособления) проверяется возможность актуального членения простого предложения на тему и рему.
